# public opinion about published articles

Tags: publications, peer-review, review-articles

As a young scientist I find it increasingly difficult to filter out the good vs not-so-good research publications. Especially given the number of publications that get published every day. Reports on retraction watch like [this one](http://retractionwatch.com/2017/04/20/new-record-major-publisher-retracting-100-studies-cancer-journal-fake-peer-reviews/), don't help. Very often some aspects of research can be missed or misinterpreted by an inexperienced young researcher.

I was wondering if there is any resource where I could suggest a publication for a quick, short commentary and obtain comments from the community? I am aware of f1000 idea but I'm not particularly fond of the subscription requirements they impose.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You could try [ScienceOpen](https://www.scienceopen.com). It's a free platform for researchers with the possibility of open comments, open peer-review and sharing research.

Comment: A journal club with your lab or department is a great way to do this on a paper-by-paper basis to get some other opinions. Obviously you won't be able to cover every single relevant paper in that setting, but it's a start and will help you learn the skills of critically reading literature. I know there are some attempts to do this on a broad basis but at least in my field the participation is far to sparse for you to likely find a write up on the paper you are interested in, and there are *so many* papers that it isn't really feasible for a small community of experts to review every paper.

Comment: If your field was biology, I would also encourage you to post *specific* questions about a particular paper on Biology.SE (not "please explain this paper for me" but "Scientist, et al. used approach XXYY to study Z, but in other papers I've read they used approach PQRS. The authors didn't mention PQRS. Is XXYY really a valid approach in this context?"). There might be another SE site that is appropriate for your interests if not biology.

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog Thanks for your suggestion, I found it useful. It seems it is not so popular to comment on publications and express individual opinions. Nevertheless, It is a great addition to my daily literature curation.

Comment: @BryanKrause lab journals are definitely a one way to go about this but it is rather very low throughput. It is also very often biased towards opinions shared between lab members, so comments provided are normally the same comments as I would have myself. Regarding different disciplines at SE, that's another good idea. It is increasingly tricky though, to gain opinions about multidisciplinary, cross-discipline papers this way. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @mjp For this reason my lab has at times had a journal club between 4-5 other labs; this worked out because we were all fairly small groups so the total participation was ~15 people. Our interests overlapped sufficiently that we would typically understand the content, if not the context (such that a key role of the presenter was to help establish context for the group) of the papers interested to others in the group, but diverged sufficiently that we would not typically read the same primary literature. The balance can be tough to achieve but definitely brought different perspectives.

Comment: One of the major journals in my field, the Journal of Neuroscience, has a relatively new ["journal club" feature](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/by/section/Journal+Club) which are brief highlight/commentary style articles with a more critical slant, written by students/postdocs, covering material previously published in the journal. I think it's a really great idea although in practice it also is very low throughput, and of course, even if you read that journal, the chances that a particular paper is covered is very slim.

Comment: @BryanKrause that's getting close to what I wish existed on a larger scale. Looking forward to other journals adapting similar features. The trouble with this approach is that many scientist are afraid to attach their scientific name to a paper rant, hence the low throughput.